# What is the Principals name and title?

Tags: corporate-law, name-title

There is a lot of info on what this is but I am unclear. I am the sole founder who inc. with clerkly and thus have a registered agent in Delaware (Not sure if this is relevant).

So when on a paper it asks: *`Principals name and title:`*, what does this mean?

Comment: This is ungrammatical and hence a little hart to understand. It also isn't entirely clear who is asking or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concluded that it is me. So I put my name and the title. Which I believe does not *have* to be the same as you put on Inc. docs

Answer (score 0):

[Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principal) defines principal, as a noun, in the relevant senses as:

> 1 : a person who has controlling authority or is in a leading
>   position: such as . . .
>
> a : a chief or head man or woman . . .
>
> c : one who engages another to act as an agent subject to general
>   control and instruction specifically : the person from whom an agent's
>   authority derives . . .
>
> e : the person primarily or ultimately liable on a legal obligation .
>   . .

In the context the question indicates, the reference is to the chief decision maker who is usually an owner as well as someone with decision making power, often without regard to whether someone is formally an officer of the company.

In the case of a single own corporation whose single owner is also the most senior executive or corporate officer, the person would be the single owner, and the title would ordinarily be "CEO" or "President" or "Founder" or "CEO and Chairman of the Board". Normally, the title would be reflected in some corporate document, although not necessarily one that is publicly filed.

Your title is up to you and can be anything you choose within reason.

Comment: So if in the incorporation docs I made a slight mistake under title, can I say founder and ceo despite that being slightly different?

Comment: @Outsider It is hard to know without knowing who is asking and why. Context is almost always very important in legal matters.

Comment: sole incorporator of a C-Corp, not that I will stay by myself for long